# Nesting glsl subroutines

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

I have a question regarding GLSL and the composition of subroutines. Simply put I want to have two subroutine types, two uniforms of those types pointing to current subroutines and several implementations of those subroutine types from which subroutines of one type are allowed to call subroutines of the other type (by means of those subroutine uniforms)

The glsl code for it would look like this:

```
subroutine float ComputeShadow(vec3 pos, ...);
subroutine float ExtractDepth(sampler2d depthmap ...);

subroutine uniform ComputeShadow u_CurrentShadowStrategy;
subroutine uniform ExtractDepth u_CurrentExtractDepth;

...
[subroutine(ComputeShadow)]
float SoftShadowAlgorithm(vec3 pos ..)
{
  ...
  float depth = u_CurrentExtractDepth( ...);
  ..
}

void main()
{
  ..
  float shadow = u_CurrentShadowStrategy( ..);
}
```

On Linux with Nvidia card and the current drivers (331.20) the application simply crashes given this piece of code when linking program for the fragment stage. The specification doesn't mention this usage at all and this use-case makes sense to me.

My question is: Is above example a reasonable use-case for the subroutines and should it work? If it shouldn't then for what reason?